# Using class fields in default functions within abstract classes

Tags: java, software-design

I am trying to build a class that can occupy three states. In these three states the object will act quite differently. I cannot simply create three classes for this because the objects will transition between states and I am not in control of how the class is initialized. All these three states must operate under one class definition.

Now as of current to pull this off I will do the following

```
enum ServerType {
    primary,
    backup,
    idle
}
class ImportantClass {
   State myState;

   // Other fields

   void commonClassFunc() {
     if (state == idle) {
       idleFoo();
     } else if (state == primary) {
       primaryFoo();
     }
     ....
   }

   // Helper functions for State primary
   void primaryFoo() {
     // Access and mutate fields
   }
   ...

   // Helper functions for State backup
   void backupFoo() {
     // Access and mutate fields
   }
   ...

   // Helper functions for State idle
   void idleBar() {
     // Access and mutate fields
   }
   ...

}
```

You can see how this will lead to a very large class definition and the state specific parts of it will only be separated by comments.

My aim is to do this in a more eloquent way.
I could for example create a Primary, Backup, and Idle class and have the ImportantClass hold one of those classes however that would not allow these methods to access the common fields. I wanted to use interfaces which allow me to do like `class ImportantClass implements Primary {}` but unfortunately even though I can define the primaryFoo method in this interface that method still won't be able to access the fields of ImportantClass.

Do you know of any ways I can structure this code such that I can break off the behavior of these three states that ImportantClass switches between while still accessing the fields of ImportantClass?

Answer (score 2):

One option to solve the problem would be as follows:
Create a new class (say `ImportantInfo`) to hold the fields that are shared among states: those common fields you want to be accessed from `ImportantClass` and the states.
You can then create the classes for each state as you wanted, and make them take an `ImportantInfo` as a constructor argument, each method can operate on these fields. So the properties of `ImportantInfo` should have public acces. However, you are not breaking encapsulation since you can make the `ImportantInfo` instance private.
In order to switch between the desired action with respect to the current state you should have the classes that make the action inherit from a common abstract class. For example have `StateImplementor` an abstract class that is constructed from an `ImportantInfo` object, and `IdleImplementor`, `PrimaryImplementor`, etc as subclasses. `StateImplementor` would have an abstract method `Foo` that is implemented in those classes. To switch between implementations you should have a `currentImplementor` object in `ImportantClass` and switch like:

```
void switchState(ServerType newState) {
    if (newState == ServerType.Idle)
        this.currentImplementor = new IdleImplementor(this.importantInfo);
}
```

Comment: How would the same object switch between these classes as it changes state?

Comment: You are right, I will edit my answer to explain that.

Comment: @TheJavatar, What if already existing instance needs to be accessed ?

Comment: @Maria If you want, you can create an instance for each implementor when you create the `ImportantClass`. You can then just switch between those instances when changing state, so you don't have to create more than one object per state.

Answer (score 1):

My general feeling here is that maybe you should make `ImportantClass` a common parent class between the classes corresponding to the three states:

```
public class ImportantClass {
    private State myState;

    // other common metadata + getters and setters
}

public class PrimaryClass extends ImportantClass {
    // fields specific to this class

    // Helper functions for State primary
    private void primaryFoo() {
    }
}
```

And so on, with classes for the other two states.

Each of the three subclasses, while not having direct access to the private parent `ImportantClass` state, would at least be able to call getters and setters to access and mutate that state.  The basic idea here is to move behaviors (read: methods) which don't belong together into separate classes.

Comment: I completely agree generally. My only issue is I am not in charge of initialization here. There is a framework that will do this I to my knowledge can’t force the superclass constructor to construct as as subclass or switch from one subclass to another. In a way the class is all three states at once too.